# Odd java integer comparision

Tags: java

If this is a duplicate I'll happily delete it, but I am unable to find it.

Why does does the 2nd comparison return false? Thanks.

```
$ cat test.java 

class test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer num1 = new Integer(0);
        Integer num2 = new Integer(0);
        num1 = 1;
        num2 = 1;

        if (num1 == num2) {
            System.out.println("Numbers are equal");
        }
        num1 = 128;
        num2 = 128;
        if (num1 == num2) {
            System.out.println("Numbers are equal using == ");
                }
        if (num1.equals(num2)) {
            System.out.println("Numbers are equal using .equals");
        }
    }
}
$ javac test.java 
$ java test
Numbers are equal
Numbers are equal using .equals
```

Comment: Integers -128 through 127 are cached internally to use the same `Integer` instance.  All other values, however, create a new `Integer` upon each declaration, so `num1` and `num2` are two different `Integer` objects.  This question has been asked before, but I don't have a link to such a duplicate.

Comment: @Vulcan you were the 1st to answer the question. Submit it as an answer and I'll mark it as answered. Thanks.

Comment: @koodawg Thanks, but I try to avoid answering duplicate questions if I know that they've been answered before, because often in cases like this, my knowledge stems from having seen the answers to the similar question(s). It'd feel unfair to receive reputation in re-posting a reworded version of what someone else has written in an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java, `Integers` should be compared using `equals()`, because they're object types, not primitives. The first example works because Java creates a pool of `Integers` between -128 and 127 (although this range can be configured), and all identity comparisons between them (using `==`) will work, because the numbers are retrieved from the pool. Larger numbers are created new each time, and the identity comparison won't work for them - that's why, to play it safe, all equality comparisons between objects must be made using `equals()`, which will always work. As you just witnessed, using `==` will work *sometimes*, but not *always*.

Comment: Re "Integers should be compared using equals" - yes, I know that. That was not my question. Thanks.

Comment: This answers your question entirely, no need to put on an attitude.

Comment: @koodawg, the answer lies in the sentence immediately after that.

Comment: *Now* it answers my question, after the verbiage about the cache between -128 and 127 was added. No attitude. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any edit history on the answer.  Were you watching the answer being typed out or loaded one sentence at a time?  Or just not being a good community member?

Comment: @SimonT Any edits within the first 5 minutes don't show up in the edit history, so it's *possible* that the answer was edited after the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Because `num1` and `num2` are declared as `Integer` types, rather than primitive `int` types, the assignments use autoboxing. The de-sugaring process uses the [`Integer.valueOf(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28int%29) method to make the conversion from `int` to `Integer`. This method is not required to cache `Integer` objects for values of 128 or more, and so a new instance is created each time the value 128 is auto-boxed.

When these two distinct objects are tested for reference equality, the result is `false`. For values from -128 to 127, the result will be true, because the cache used by the `valueOf()` method consistently returns the same instance.